# Robolectric ShadowAsyncTask this action is not supported in PAUSED mode

Tags: android, robolectric

The following has been working for Robolectric 4.2

```java
@Implements(AsyncTask.class)
public class MyShadowAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
    extends ShadowAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

  @Implementation
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> executeOnExecutor(
      Executor executor, Params... params) {
    return super.execute(params);
  }
}
```

Method `.execute` doesn't seem to exist in 4.4 anymore

so I tried

1. ShadowLegacyAsyncTask

```java
@Implements(AsyncTask.class)
public class CmbShadowAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
    extends ShadowLegacyAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

  @Implementation
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> executeOnExecutor(
      Executor executor, Params... params) {
    return super.executeOnExecutor(executor, params);
  }
}
```

got me

```
Exception in thread "AsyncTask #1" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: post is not supported in PAUSED LooperMode
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLegacyAsyncTask$1.done(ShadowLegacyAsyncTask.java:66)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:381)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.set(FutureTask.java:232)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:272)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLegacyAsyncTask$3.run(ShadowLegacyAsyncTask.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: post is not supported in PAUSED LooperMode
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.LooperDelegatingScheduler.post(LooperDelegatingScheduler.java:62)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLegacyAsyncTask$1.done(ShadowLegacyAsyncTask.java:43)
    ... 7 more

this action is not supported in PAUSED mode.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: this action is not supported in PAUSED mode.
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.assertLooperMode(ShadowLooper.java:27)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplication.getBackgroundThreadScheduler(ShadowApplication.java:113)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLegacyAsyncTask.execute(ShadowLegacyAsyncTask.java:104)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java)
```

2. ShadowPausedAsyncTask

```java
@Implements(AsyncTask.class)
public class CmbShadowAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
    extends ShadowPausedAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

  @Implementation
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> executeOnExecutor(
      Executor executor, Params... params) {
    return super.executeOnExecutor(executor, params);
  }
}
```

got me

```
this action is not supported in PAUSED mode.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: this action is not supported in PAUSED mode.
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.assertLooperMode(ShadowLooper.java:27)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplication.getBackgroundThreadScheduler(ShadowApplication.java:113)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.getBackgroundThreadScheduler(Robolectric.java:346)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.flushBackgroundThreadScheduler(Robolectric.java:353)
```

Java version 11
Gradle version 6.7.1
AGP version 4.3.1

Comment: It seems the usage of `ShadowPausedAsyncTask` to be the right movement.

Can you share a unit test snippet which generates `IllegalStateException` when we employ the `ShadowPausedAsyncTask` class, Eric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the maintainer of Robolectric, the migrations steps are

1. Used ShadowLegacyAsyncTask
2. Used `@LooperMode(LEGACY)` for every test
3. Add `shadowOf(Looper.getMainLooper()).idle()` to every trigger in every test

Reference: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/6925